# When app is hot restarted the length of column's children doubles in size

Tags: flutter

There is a service:

```
  List<String> letters = [];

  Future<List<String>> fetchMessages(BuildContext context) async {
    letters.clear(); // clears list at first
    ...
    // gets from external webservice and fill out the letters list
    return letters;
  }
```

and a stateless widget:

```
FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
  future: fetchMessages(context),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<String>> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      List<String> data = snapshot.data;
      return _messagesView(context, data); // use the data
...  
      
// _messagesView
Column(
  children: [
    for (var e in data) Message(e),
  ],
),
```

The problem is that the length of the column's children doubles when the app is hot restarted.

The source list from the `fetchMessages` should be cleared every time the messages fetched. Then why the column's children grows?

Comment: did you put the `fetchMessages` inside `init state` ?

Comment: @Boby the widget is stateless

Comment: do you really mean `hot restart` (full restart)?

Comment: @pskink I mean Flutter Hot Restart button ( Ctrl + Shift + \ ) in Android  studio.

Comment: @pskink when `hot reload` used then the widget works as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are clearing the list before doing some async work. So if for some reason the async work is not done when starting it again you will get double entries since both tasks will be insterting into the same list (hot restart can cause multiple rebuilds in some cases)

To fix this simply make the list within the method and return it instead of keeping a list outside of the future